# Creating 'fake' microphone and camera inputs on an Android mobile

Tags: audio, video, microphone, webcam

*Disclaimer: I don't own an android mobile, but would definitely get one if the below were possible.*

On my mac, I can use software like [CamTwist](http://camtwiststudio.com) and [SoundSiphon](http://staticz.com/soundsiphon/) to create 'fake' webcam and microphone inputs.

CamTwist lets me pipe custom content (such as images or video) to that webcamera input, and SoundSiphon makes it easy to have system audio interpreted as microphone input.

---

**Q. Is it possible to achieve something similar to the above, but on any Android handheld?**

E.g. I'd like to be able to use a native Android app (such as Skype or Periscope) and pipe custom video to it (rather than using the in-built camera), whilst simultaneously broadcasting a custom audio file (rather than the in-built microphone)

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Firelord—I couldn't find any apps that accomplish this. Perhaps I should expand on my disclaimer: I've never owned an android device and in turn, have never ''rooted' a device. I'm familiar with the command line on mac but have never built a Linux distro. In hindsight, perhaps asking on this stackexchange wasn't the best idea—I was more just wondering if this is possible in _theory_, after which I could then explore further. This kernel module looks relevant (https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback) though once again, not sure how applicable it is. Any starting points welcome.