# Use image file as camera

Tags: camera, android-emulator

I need to use an image file instead of a camera for Android apps that want you to use a camera app to take a photo (for example, Google Drive scanner). I don't need to use apps that use the camera directly, such as WhatsApp.

*The question was edited so it matches the answers. See edit history to see the actual question.*

Comment: For emulating *built-in in-app* camera: [Creating 'fake' microphone and camera inputs on an Android mobile](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/110505), [How to emulate camera input in Android? (To activate WhatsApp Web)](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/145020)

Answer (score 14):

There are 3rd-party "fake camera" apps that will let you to choose an image instead, such as:

- <s>Image2Camera ([free](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ghostflying.image2camera))</s>
- <s>Fake Camera by New Horizon Apps ([free](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.blogspot.newapphorizons.fakecamera))</s>
- Fake Camera - donate version by Vaclav Balak ([paid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cz.shmoula.android.fakecamera.donate))

Note that *you need to have the image inside the (emulator) device storage first* for these apps to be useful.

Also, since these apps are not really a camera app, opening the apps directly won't be really useful (other than, perhaps, to read the instruction for app usage). Instead, when you want to take a picture from an app, these apps will be selectable as "camera" app instead, then you can select the image on the device.

**Disclaimer**: I'm not affiliated with any of these apps.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm just not understanding this. How can this be beneficial. I know you know your stuff, you provide excellent answers. Can you give me a decent link on reading more about this?

Comment: @HasH_BrowN basically, when an app requests the user to provide an image, Android by default doesn't provide a way to select **both** from gallery and camera; [only 1 source can be used](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2708128/2821954). The general solution is to provide a menu to choose the source (implemented manually by the developer). This makes a problem when an app *only* requests to take a picture from the camera; you may have a better picture stored in the device, or can't take a photo now. The only solution is to make the "fake camera" work as a "gallery".

Comment: Also, in this specific case, OP is using Android emulator; [the camera would work if OP had a webcam](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#overview). Similar benefits are for device which doesn't have hardware camera while using an app that needs it (ideally Play Store will prevent this app to be installed in such devices, provided if the developers specify it, but either way for apps from 3rd-party market, there's no checking and it can be installed either way)

Comment: Thank you. That makes total sense an I now see that could be really useful under various situations. Thank for the summary