# How to emulate camera input in Android? (To activate Whatsapp Web)

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, camera, emulators, qr-code

I have an Android device without a camera and I run Whatsapp on that device.

I want to activate Whatsapp Web from this device. Unfortunately, the only way to do this is to scan a QR-code, and I can't do that as I have no camera.

So, if I just could emulate camera input, that means use an image or video file of the QR code and have that be taken by the OS as camera input, then I would solve the problem.

This [is doable on Windows.](http://www.webcamsimulator.com/Webcam-Simulator.asp) I'm sure it should be doable on a rooted Android device as well, especially if we can use Xposed Framework.

But the question is, does anybody know how to?

Comment: I think those answers on [Use image file as camera](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/124751/use-image-file-as-camera) will help you. I don't know if it works for video, too, but to activate WhatsApp Web a static image should be enough.

Comment: That's a nice idea, but unfortunately, Whatsapp doesn't use the "Complete action with" dialogue. It has its own built in camera in the app itself, so a third party app won't work. It has to be some sort of tweak, Xposed module or something that takes control of all camera input systemwide.

Comment: Connect a webcam to your Android phone, and use an app like this one: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vaultmicro.camerafi&hl=en