# How can I use another phone's camera in place of my camera?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, camera

Ok, the problem is my camera's protective glass cover has wore down and now some dust has entered, causing the camera's output to become blurred. This is causing me a lot of issues currently, especially when I need to scan some QR code. For example, now I can't login to WhatsApp on my PC, cuz I need to scan their QR code with my phone.

What I want is, use another phone's camera instead of my phone's camera, just like the DroidCam functionality, where you use your phone's camera instead of your PC's camera. Are there any apps designed for this purpose?

Comment: Related: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/145020/218526

Answer (score 0):

## Here's my suggestions:

- ***Firstly:*** If your phone has a front-facing camera, use that.
- ***Secondly:*** grab a can of air duster and spray the rear-facing camera out( if this clears it up, then find a crystal clear tape and cover it. Or get a case that covers it.)
- ***Lastly:*** I'm taking the assumption that you do have another phone. If so, just take the photo and transfer(via bluetooth, text, cloud, etc.) it.

Hope something helps.

T.Swain

Comment: I don't think it is possible to use the front camera to scan the WhatsApp Web QR code. Same for the last solution - it is not possible to select a photo from the gallery instead of scanning the QR code. I will try the second solution.

Answer (score 0):

For your question, I recommend using an external camera that is plugged into the USB port of your phone camera. But for other phone 'camera mirroring' applications I have not found it, but it can be made. Just like you said, it works like the DroidCam application. Or using other means such as USB Debugging, WiFi and Bluetooth connection, or using IP (such as Video Call).

Comment: What do you mean by USB port? My phone does not have one.