# Use image file as camera (Android 10)

Tags: camera

Instead of using the real camera, I would like to simulate the camera input as a static image file. I want it to work with any app, as if it was a camera. This question had been answered [Use image file as camera](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/124751/use-image-file-as-camera) but it doesn't work with Android 10.

The real world use case is that I will need to scan a QR code / tag from WeChat in order to use WeChat official accounts, and WeChat made it mandatory to do it via the camera. You can test it on: https://mp.weixin.qq.com/ (You will need to register an account first obviously...)

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/124751/use-image-file-as-camera

Comment: If it's a built-in in-app camera, then https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/145020/how-to-emulate-camera-input-in-android-to-activate-whatsapp-web?noredirect=1&lq=1 should be more relevant, though there's no satisfying answer yet.

Comment: @AndrewT. someone in that question referred to https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/124751/use-image-file-as-camera which is not working for Android 10. So I am guess in Android 10 this is not doable.

Comment: It's a different use-case: Q #124751 (mentioned on this question) was interpreted as *taking a photo* from an image file, whereas Q #145020 is about emulating camera input (e.g. scanning barcode/QR) from a file. The answer (now converted to comment because it's essentially a link-only answer) on Q #145020 that referred to #124751 doesn't apply. So, it's not because of Android 10, but it's a different use-case and not yet answered.