# How to stream an image into camera source trough ADB?

Tags: adb, camera

I am trying to **stream** an **image** into the **camera source** of an Android 10 device through `adb`.

This should effect on all apps that use the camera source and not only using specific camera apps.

Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use image file as camera](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/124751/use-image-file-as-camera)

Comment: @Robert unfortunately not. The image should be streamed in the camera source itself, thus affecting the low-level device IO.Thanks for the input.

Comment: Most likely what you want is only possible with root permissions and system modification. The only rootless solution I see is using an external USB device that claims to be an USB webcam and allows you to upload the image it later sends back to Android as live image. Not sure if such a device already exists.

Comment: I have full control over the device: in fact, it's just a solution for my own device and not a distributed implementation. May I get more insights on how to achieve this, given that I have full control over android?

Comment: I don't know what concrete steps have to be performed, but my starting point would be to implement a custom [CameraDevice](https://source.android.com/devices/camera/camera3) layer and then install it on the device replacing the existing CameraDevice implementation. May be the source code of the Android emulator and it's way to provide the camera data to the emulator is helpful to understand how an external image can be injected into the device.

Comment: @Robert thank you for this. It seems very complicated, actually - I was trying to replicate something like what emulators do when you try to use the camera: they let you upload a video, an image or use an USB-Camera connected to the PC. In my case I am not using any emulator (using a phone is mandatory), but if the only solution is such a "low level workaround", then I might have to stick with it - unless I'm missing something.

Comment: If you want to supply static images to one app only on a rooted device I would give Frida a try. It allows to manipulate the app at run-time. Still a bit of work but I assume it would be achievable with much less work.