# Is it possible to use virtual camera on android phone?

Tags: applications, google-play-store, rooting, settings, camera

Well i know it's possible via Emulators or vm , but my question is about  an actual android phone
is it possible to do something like manycam on windows ?

i've been searching internet for almost two days and can't find any useful information even either if it's possible or not

Comment: This question seems similar to: [How to stream an image into camera source trough ADB?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/226175/3573)

Comment: The question is not clear.. I am assuming that you want to use your 1st phone's camera in 2nd phone(correct me if I'm wrong). For this you can use 1st phone as ip camera and with the 2nd phone you can recieve the footage sent by the 1st camera

Comment: @Aayush no buddy , i want to use a video as a camera input

Comment: the screenshots and description here looks convincing..  https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.visicommedia.manycam&hl=en   It seems to be a little complex to use

Comment: I only could do that on android emulator running on Windows system