# How to stream an image into camera source?

Tags: camera, hardware, virtualization, webcam

This is basically the same question as
[How to stream an image into camera source trough ADB?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/226175/how-to-stream-an-image-into-camera-source-trough-adb)

I am trying to stream an image into the camera source of an Android device. This should ideally have effect on all apps that use the camera source.
The solution doesn't have to be by using ADB.

(Sorry my technical understanding is very limited. I was going to comment instead but didn't have enough reputation. Thanks!)

Comment: https://github.com/GhostFlying/image-to-camera; You can download the app from https://apkpure.com/image2camera/com.ghostflying.image2camera. Check if this works

Comment: Thanks. I think this won't work because it looks more like an image picker tool. What I was looking for is, when apps request live camera access, an existing image/video file automatically replaces the camera function. I thought the other thread's OP was looking for the same thing? Am I wrong?

Comment: Is this something that's likely impossible with today's Android technology, or is it just that few people are interested?