# use selected photo or video as camera

Tags: applications, camera, photos

Some applications do not allow you to choose an application such as fake camera to take photos (such as verification app), they only allow you to use the default camera of the smartphone. Is there a way to set photos or videos as the default camera? so that any app that has the use of the camera only see the photo I selected? the phone model is indifferent, please tell me the most suitable.
Thanks for your suggestions :)

Comment: Related (but no answers yet): [Creating 'fake' microphone and camera inputs on an Android mobile](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/110505/44325), [How to emulate camera input in Android?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/145020/44325)